# Integral $ \int e^{x} \sqrt{e^{x} - 1} dx $

Tags: integration, partitions-for-integration

I want to determinate the following integral  $\int e^{x} \sqrt{e^{x} - 1} dx$

My try and steps were as follow

$$ \int e^{x} \sqrt{e^{x} - 1} dx $$

let $ u = \sqrt{e^{x} - 1} $ and $ v' = e^{x} $

$$ \to e^{x} \sqrt{e^{x} - 1} - \int \frac{e^{x}}{2\sqrt{e^{x}-1}} e^{x} dx$$

let $ u = e^{x} $ and $ v' = \frac{e^{x}}{2\sqrt{e^{x}-1}} $

$$ \to e^{x} \sqrt{e^{x} - 1} - (e^{x} \sqrt{e^{x} - 1} - \int e^{x}\sqrt{e^{x}-1} dx )
\\ = e^{x} \sqrt{e^{x} - 1} - e^{x} \sqrt{e^{x} - 1} + \int e^{x}\sqrt{e^{x}-1} dx
\\ = 0 + \int e^{x}\sqrt{e^{x}-1} dx
$$

What am I missing or doing wrong? Is it not allowed to change the $u$ & $v'$ when doing the 2nd time partition?

Comment: Let's review what you did: beginning with $\int f(x)g'(x)\, dx$, you set $u = f(x)$ and $v' = g'(x)dx$ to get $fg - \int f'(x)g(x)\, dx$.  Then you set $u = g(x)$ and $v' = f'(x)dx$ to get $fg - fg + \int f(x)g'(x)\, dx$.  That's why you didn't get anywhere.

Comment: You might try just substituting instead...

Comment: oh yeah thanks ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Hint** You don't need integration by parts for this problem. Let $u=e^x-1$.

Answer (score 3):

You are overcomplicating it. Look at this quickly:

$$ \int e^{x} \sqrt{e^{x} - 1} dx $$

Note that:

$$\frac{d}{dx}e^x=e^x$$

Well, jolly gosh! We've basically got $e^x$ in that square root! Let's use u-substitution. The inside of the root is $u$:

$$u=e^{x} - 1$$
$$du=e^{x} dx$$

Rewrite the equation as follows:

$$ \int u^{\frac{1}{2}} du $$

Hence, the integral of that would be:

$$\frac{2}{3}u^{\frac{3}{2}}$$

Substituting $u$ back:

$$\frac{2}{3}(e^{x} - 1)^{\frac{3}{2}}$$

For future, try using WolframAlpha for basic integrals. Cheers!
-Shahar

Comment: That was strange. I'll upvote your answer once I have the capability to do so.

Answer (score 2):

$$ \int e^{x} \sqrt{e^{x} - 1} dx $$

Make these substitution:
$$u=e^{x} - 1$$
$$du=e^{x} dx$$

Rewrite it like this:

$$ \int u^{\frac{1}{2}} du $$

Take the integral:

$$\frac{2}{3}u^{\frac{3}{2}}$$

Finally you get:

$$\frac{2}{3}(e^{x} - 1)^{\frac{3}{2}}$$

Comment: What the... Your answer is identical to mine.

Comment: Wow that's funny... I posted it after yours would you like me to take it down? What a coincidence. @Shahar

Comment: No, don't take it down but I just wanted to say that it's weird.